# How to Render JSON in New VSCode Notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image: JSON doesn't render any more]

After updating my VSCode to latest (1.65.2 for Mac), I've found that JSON no longer gets rendered in my notebooks. I believe that used to work in a previous version.

After some research I couldn't find any release notes that would explain this change. What's the correct approach to do this now?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. I tried many things to solve it that didn't work but ultimately what worked was re-installing VSCode. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `JSON(myjson)` and not `display(JSON(myjson))`...